# Forwarding references and converting constructors in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, forwarding-reference

Suppose I want to create a function that takes both lvalue and rvalue string arguments by refernce, converts them to upper case, and prints them to standard output:

```
void upper_print(std::string& s);
void upper_print(std::string&& s);
```

This works fine as follows:

```
std::string s("Hello world");
upper_print(s);
upper_print(std::string("Hello world"));
upper_print("Hello world"); // converting ctor used
```

However, to avoid redundancy, I want to use a forwarding reference instead:

```
template <typename T> upper_print(T&& s);
```

Unfortunately, then I cannot invoke `upper_print` with a string literal argument:

```
std::string s("Hello world"); // OK
upper_print(s); // OK
upper_print(std::string("Hello world")); // OK
upper_print("Hello world"); // ERROR
```

I am aware of the possibility to restrict arguments to `std::string` objects, e.g., by using `std::enable_if` or `static_assert`. But it does not help here.

Is there any option to combine the functionality of forwarding references and converting constructor in this sense?

Comment: What's the reason you want to do this way? Why don't you use `const std::string &` as parameter? It has the additional benefit that you will have only one function, instead of 3.

Comment: @geza Because to convert the string you need a non-const string.

Comment: @RickAstley: that's a smelly design. I don't expect a function called `upper_print` modifying the string. And I cannot find a good name for this functionality either.

Comment: @geza: This is just a MWE. More generally, forwarding references combine two independent properties: 1) they can bind to both lvalues and rvalues, 2) they can bind to objects of any types. Wouldn't be useful to also have references with just the first one? That is, **references that can bind to lvalues and rvalues but of particular type only**?

Comment: @geza: Suppose the function is called `convert_to_upper_and_print` instead.

Comment: @DanielLangr: What would this function do? Convert the parameter to upper, and print it? If yes, then what does `convert_to_upper_and_print("Hello");` do? How can it convert a static string to upper?

Comment: Anyway, this can be achieved with some explicit (`const char *` and `char[S]`) `upper_print` functions, which forward the work to the templated `upper_print` function.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Sure. For me, the problem is not that. If you have a function, which functionality is to convert its parameter to upper, then I don't expect that I can call it with a constant value, as it cannot be converted. But it is just me. And it is a bad design for me for the other reason I mentioned: you'll have several template instantiations, which basically do the same. More compiled code for nothing.

Comment: @geza: I simply compare the two cases. In the first one, I can call `upper_print("Hello world");` and its perfectly fine. A temporary `std::string` object is created, which is not constant. With forwarding references, I can't do the same.

Comment: @DanielLangr: yes, I understand the problem :) I just wanted to draw attention that I think that this is a bad design (for me, I'd never do a function like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a solution like this?

```
template <typename T>
void upper_print_helper(T&& s);

inline void upper_print(std::string&& s) {
    upper_print_helper(std::move(s));
}
inline void upper_print(std::string& s) {
    upper_print_helper(s);
}
```